# How to create a drawable from Java in Android?

Tags: java, android, border, drawable, shapes

How can i create a rectangle drawable with border only not filling the color from code not from XML... 
Is there any way to accomplish this using code? 
Really Appreciate your helps...

Thanks @Xaver and @Vipul for the Answer :D

EDIT:

You can create a Drawable with a border around it just like @vipulmittal suggested by using a GradientDrawable.

```
GradientDrawable drawable = new GradientDrawable();
drawable.setStroke(width, Color.RED);
```

EDIT2:

The setBackground method is for API level 16 and up and setBackgroundDrawable is used for anything below API level 16. So what you have to do is something like this:

```
// Build.VERSION_CODES.JELLY_BEAN is API LEVEL 16
if (android.os.Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.JELLY_BEAN) {
    imageView.setBackground(drawable);
} else {
    imageView.setBackgroundDrawable(drawable);
}
```

I tend to create a helper method for cases like this:

```
public static void setBackground(ImageView imageView, Drawable drawable) {

    // Build.VERSION_CODES.JELLY_BEAN is API LEVEL 16
    if (android.os.Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.JELLY_BEAN) {
        imageView.setBackground(drawable);
    } else {
        imageView.setBackgroundDrawable(drawable);
    }
}
```

And then everytime you set the background of a ImageView you just have to call:

```
ImageViewHelper.setBackground(imageView, drawable);
```

Comment: see http://developer.android.com/reference/android/graphics/drawable/GradientDrawable.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can create a Bitmap with a solid color like this:

```
Bitmap bitmap = Bitmap.createBitmap(1, 1, Config.ARGB_8888);
bitmap.setPixel(0, 0, Color.BLUE); // Set color to blue

Bitmap resultBitmap = Bitmap.createScaledBitmap(bitmap, width, height, true);
bitmap.recycle();
```

You can than wrap it with `BitmapDrawable` if you really need a `Drawable` but I can't really tell from your question what you need it for.

```
BitmapDrawable drawable = new BitmapDrawable(resultBitmap);
```

**EDIT:**

You can create a `Drawable` with a border around it just like @vipulmittal suggested by using a `GradientDrawable`.

```
GradientDrawable drawable = new GradientDrawable();
drawable.setStroke(width, Color.RED);
```

**EDIT2:**

The `setBackground` method is for API level 16 and up and `setBackgroundDrawable` is used for anything below API level 16. So what you have to do is something like this:

```
// Build.VERSION_CODES.JELLY_BEAN is API LEVEL 16
if (android.os.Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.JELLY_BEAN) {
    imageView.setBackground(drawable);
} else {
    imageView.setBackgroundDrawable(drawable);
}
```

I tend to create a helper method for cases like this:

```
public static void setBackground(ImageView imageView, Drawable drawable) {

    // Build.VERSION_CODES.JELLY_BEAN is API LEVEL 16
    if (android.os.Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.JELLY_BEAN) {
        imageView.setBackground(drawable);
    } else {
        imageView.setBackgroundDrawable(drawable);
    }
}
```

And then everytime you set the background of a `ImageView` you just have to call:

```
ImageViewHelper.setBackground(imageView, drawable);
```

Comment: I'm sorry I coludn't make it clear to you... But I want a drawable to act as a border to an image ... The border color needs to be changed during the runtime, if a new color has been returned from Json

Comment: I misunderstood. @vipulmittal has the answer you are looking for.

Comment: @Xavier... Thanks for the setImageDrawable suggestion but it kind of replaced with the image.... Only the border is visible now...
I used the follwing code...
serviceImg.setImageResource(R.id.image);   serviceImg.setImageDrawable(ConstantValues.createImageBorder());

Comment: Oh, I understand what you are trying to do. Give me a few minutes and I will post a solution.

Comment: I'm just looking at the docs and there should be no problem setting a `Drawable` with setBackground in API level 10. `setBackground` is supported since API level 1. Only `setBackgroundDrawable` was deprecated in API level 16. Were you using `setBackgroundDrawable`?

Comment: I am using the setBackground method but it is giving me the 
serviceImg.setBackground(ConstantValues.createImageBorder());
When i pressed Ctrl+Space it showed me the following description :-
public void setBackground (Drawable background) 

Added in API level 16

Comment: Ok I understand, I will edit a solution in my question.

Answer (score 1):

You can simply create a gradient drawable object and set stroke to it.

```
    GradientDrawable gd=new GradientDrawable();
    gd.setStroke(1, Color.RED);
```

Just set this as background of any view and it will draw border to the view.

Comment: Thanks for your ans.. This helped me ...
But isn't there a way to make it work from devices which have 2.3.3 gingerbread and up....

Comment: This Suggestion is given by the imageview.setBackground(getGDrawable) method....
Call requires API level 16 (current min is 10): android.widget.ImageView#setBackground

And it suggests me to supprees like New APi, Locked jellyBean...

Comment: You need to call the method `setImageDrawable(drawable)` on the `ImageView`. Not `setBackground`

Comment: Thanks it solved the problem but it also replaced the image making only the border visible....